# sh script difference between kubuntu 14.04 and 16.04

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm moving from Kubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 by starting with a fresh 16.04 install and porting my code and am seeing a difference in script processing between the two versions.

Here's the setup.  I'm in a directory containing both an executable (dtc) and a subdirectory containing an sh script (dtc-version).  If 'dtc' is invoked with the -v argument, it simply prints its version.  Here is the relevant portion of 'dtc-version':

```
#!/bin/sh

dtc="$*"
MAJOR=$($dtc -v | head -1 | awk '{print $NF}' | cut -d . -f 1)
...
```

In 14.04, I can successfully run this as

```
scripts/dtc-version dtc
```

In 16.04, that same invocation fails as follows:

```
scripts/dtc-version.sh: line 4: dtc: command not found
```

I can run it successfully via this invocation:

```
scripts/dtc-version ./dtc
```

In both versions, my shell is bash and my $PATH is identical and does NOT include '.'

If I add '.' to my path, the 16.04 version works using the unadorned 'dtc' argument however that is not an acceptable solution as bitbake yells at me if I have '.' in my path.

Comment: Without seeing `dtc-version`, it's really impossible to tell. It's conceivable that it respects your aliases and/or functions. Did you have an alias or function for "dtc" in your old ubuntu? In the old ubuntu, what do you get with `type -a dtc`? Does that differ in the new installation?

Comment: Seems that you are using command with relative path to executable. I recommend using absolute path instead.

Answer (score 0):

@glenn jackman provided the relevant clue.  It turns out that at some point in my old system 'dtc' had been copied to '/usr/bin'.  In my old system, `type -a dtc` yielded `dtc is /usr/bin/dtc` while on my new system it yielded `bash: type: dtc: not found`.

This is all part of an insanely complex build system with all sorts of setup steps and that has morphed several times.  In spite of following a set of work instructions, I must have skipped a step.  I didn't occur to me try 'type' myself because obviously that couldn't be the problem ;-)

Thanks to all that commented!!!